# Backrefrences in multi-line java regex

Tags: java, regex, backreference

Trying to write a stylechecker for some code and using backrefrences in Java for a multiline regex... here's what the regex looks like

`.*import com.+([a-zA-Z]+Factory\.class).*\\1.*`

Basically, want to find the first instance of a factory class in my code. My example code looks like this:

```
import com.sample.OtherClass;
import com.sample.cool.SomeFactory.class;

// other nonsense

@Import(clazz = SomeFactory.class)
// other nonsense
```

My expected match would be the `SomeFactory.class` in the `@Import` statement, but it doesn't pick this up... any suggestions?

Comment: Do nor forget to use `Pattern.DOTALL` flag when you compile a pattern.

Comment: can you add your expected match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?s)import\s+com.+?\.([a-zA-Z]+Factory\.class).*(\1)
```

In Java use:

```
final String regex = "(?s)import\\s+com.+?\\.([a-zA-Z]+Factory\\.class).*(\\1)";
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pNKkjY/1)

Captured group #1 is `SomeFactory.class` after import line and captured group #2 is `SomeFactory.class` after `@Import` line.